# undefined method `paginate' for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, kaminari

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.2.1 and Kaminari gem 0.13.0.

I have added `gem 'kaminari'` in my gemfile, then ran `Bundle install`.

In controller I have `@posts = Post.order("name").page(params[:page])`

In view:

```
<%= paginate @posts%>
        <% @posts.each{|posts| %>
            <h1 class="title"><%= link_to posts.title, posts %></h1>
                <p class="byline">Raksts izveidots: <%= posts.created_at.utc.strftime("%d.%m.%Y") %></p>
                <div class="entry">
                    <p><%= posts.content %></p>
                </div>
            <p class="meta"><a href="#" class="more">Read More</a> &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <a href="#" class="comments">Comments</a> (33)</p>           
        <% } %>
        <%= paginate @posts%>
```

But in result I have `undefined method 'paginate' for #<#<Class:0x3cf68b8>:0x2ab92b0>`.

Anyone could help me?

```
 class PostsController < ApplicationController
    # GET /posts
    # GET /posts.json
    def index
      @posts = Post.order(:name).page(params[:page]).per(2)
      @posts = Post.order('posts.id DESC')


      respond_to do |format|
        format.html  #index.html.erb
        format.json { render json: @posts }
      end
    end
```

Comment: did you restart your rails server?

Comment: Just done it, but now I got another error. `undefined method 'current_page' for`

Comment: `undefined method 'current_page' for#<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x409fba8>` Extracted source (around line #5): `<%= paginate @posts%>`

Comment: You redefine paginated collection by `@posts = Post.order('posts.id DESC')`. Remove this line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
def index
  @posts = Post.order(:name).page(params[:page]).per(2)

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html  #index.html.erb
    format.json { render json: @posts }
  end
end
```

Comment: But how I can now order posts by created date?

Comment: just pass multiple parameters to the order method like Post.order(:name,'id DESC').page(params[:page]).per(2)

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do:

```
@posts = Post.order(:name).page(params[:page]).per(2), order: 'post_id desc',
                                                         per_page: 10
```

Hope this helps.